# Cross-technology documentation topics

Tags: discussion, documentation

Some of topics are linked with another technology.

For example when we write about [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/1258/model-binding#t=201607212159596060135) we more or less talk about `jQuery` or other client side framework.

I also want to write one or two more exaples there but in my example I want to use `$.param()` and `$.serialize()` functions to show how easy can Model binding can be if you combine technologies smart way.

But I not sure is that acceptable this kind cross-technolgy examples in Documentation?

Where is the line what you can and what you can't write in there?

Comment: If I remember correctly they wanted to support using different languages in a single example. Anyway I guess you could just put your example using cross-technologies in the tag/topic where it fits most and then link to other related tags/topics. I guess it would be helpful to have cross-technology topics in tags.